# JAXB with variable number of @XMLElements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Following the tutorial given in http://blog.adamsbros.org/2010/02/07/jaxb-example-code/ I'd like to know if it is possible to have variable number of XMLElements.
For example, my class will be:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
public class Teacher {

@XmlAttribute
String TeacherName;

@XmlElement
List<String> StudentNames = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

I would like JAXB to create a XML such as:

```
<Teacher TeacherName="Mary">
 <StudentName>John</StudentName>
 <StudentName>Paul</StudentName>
</Teacher>
```

Is this possible to have variable number of elements with JAXB or is there a better way to handle something like this? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is that really the question? Ans is ofcourse you can have as many as you want so go nuts:) . What are your concerns???

Comment: Thanks Shahzeb. It works automatically with lists too. I thought I need to do special processing to get multiple elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I have modified the metadata you provided in your question to match your desired XML document.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Teacher {

    @XmlAttribute(name="TeacherName")
    String TeacherName;

    @XmlElement(name="StudentName")
    List<String> StudentNames = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Comment: Thanks Blaise. I'm starting to get the hang of it. But a little confused how it works inside. I mean does it need to have an iterator and toString() for it work? because this didnt work when I replaced ArrayList with a Map. Complained that Map is an interface and JAXB doesnt support interfaces. But ArrayList is an interface too.

Comment: @madu - `ArrayList` is a class that implements an interface `List`. `Map` is an interface and it is implemented by `HashMap` class

Comment: @Amanpreet Thanks. Got it now. But can you tell me what the requirement of JAXB is? I know it works for Strings, but in general, whatever I have inside the List need to be implement toString()? Thank you

Comment: @madu - I think you should refer the use of generics with collections: http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2008/05/java-generics-examples-use-generics-in.html . JAXB will work with all objects types. It depends on what your xml file's schema definition is.

Comment: @madu - JAXB implementations (MOXy, Metro, JaxMe) do not use an objects toString method.  The spec (JSR-222) defines how the simple types (String, int, Date, Long) are represented as XML, and the POJOs are converted based on their JAXB metadata.

Comment: @Amanpreet, Blaise- Thank you very much. I will refer to the spec in more detail. Cheers.

Comment: @madu - The following may help:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted.  Also my Java XML & JSON Binding blog (http://blog.bdoughan.com/) has many JAXB examples.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are concerned about getting the size then we have `size()` method in `ArrayList` class.

Comment: Thanks Amanpreet. But size isn't what I was looking for. I wanted to get all the elements with same XML tag.